# How to handle two column article layout when there are figure?

Tags: floats, two-column, templates, double-sided, article

I'm having big trouble with a two column article I'm working on, I'm using a template.
The problem is that when I add image of big dimension all the layout change and white space appears all over, and other problems arise like images are in wrong order or they are found after the bibliography.To sum up there is strange behaviour.
What I should do? I tried to fix the image in some position with `\usepackage{float}` but it does not work.
I'm using texmaker.
any advice is well accepted

Comment: Without you providing further information on the documentclass you use (is it really `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` as the text in your question indicates or something different?) it is quite hard to tell you what went wrong. Also, does an "image of big dimensions"  refer to an image that is as wide as both columns? Do you use `figure` or `figure*`? To summarize: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Thanks, the article is heavy because of lots of images, I don't know if it is of any help but I'm using an article template  called "Stylish article"  at www.latextemplate.com , and no I'm using just \includegraphics , and with image of big dimension I mean that is long , it takes lot of space of a column but it is not two column wide. If this is not of any help I will try to produce some minimal working example

Answer (score 1):

In a two column document use the `figure*` environment if the illustration is wider than a column. This will put the figure at the top of the page spanning both columns.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
% preamble stuff
\begin{document}
% some text
\begin{figure*}
\centering
ILLUSTRATION WIDER THAN ONE COLUMN
\caption{Spanning two columns}
\end{figure*}
% more stuff
\end{document}
```